# Inflating RelativeLayout View into horizontal scroll view deletes layout settings

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout, horizontalscrollview

Sorry for the long question..
I have Relativelayout of elements I am adding dynamically into Linearlayout of Horizontalscrollview.
When I see the layout the preview seems great, but when I am adding it programmatically it ruins the view.. the Text moved to another locations on the layout, and the padding is ignored..

This is the Relativelayout element deal_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/deal_layout"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:src="@drawable/deal_square"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="deals background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/from_to_deals_txt"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="from "
            android:textAppearance="@style/from_to_deals"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Source"
            android:textAppearance="@style/source_deals"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" to "
            android:textAppearance="@style/from_to_deals"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="destination"
        android:textAppearance="@style/dst_deals"
        android:layout_below="@id/from_to_deals_txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/from_to_deals_txt"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/dst_deals_txt"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1099 X"
        android:textAppearance="@style/price_deals"
        android:layout_below="@id/dst_deals_txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/from_to_deals_txt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/from_to_deals_txt"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/price_deal_txt"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Horizontal scroll view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dealsView"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            >

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding the Relativelayout elements with this java function:

```
LinearLayout dealsView;
dealsView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dealsView);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View cur_deal = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_layout, null);
    dealsView.addView(cur_deal);
}
```

In the preview it looks like this:
[image]
On the application it looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone has idea what am I doing wrong?

When I am adding the elements with copy paste to the linearlayout it seems great, and the margin is works fine, only from the code it not works..

Thanks!

Comment: instead of passing R.layout.your_layout, null to the inflater pass R.layout.your_layout, dealsView, false

Comment: works, can you please write it as an answer and I will mark it, also, can you explain the difference between the methods? Thsnk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing null to the `inflater`, pass the Views intended parent (dealsView) so that the `LayoutParams` from the root can be used to inflate.

```
View cur_deal = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_layout, dealsView, false);
```

I believe the issue is caused by all of your Views using `width="wrap_content"` but without the `inflater` knowing the root it cannot properly inflate that value.